# Monitor mode на Qualcomm QCA9377(rev 31)

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Не могу перевести в монитор мод QCA9377 обычным способом в iwconfig показывает "wlan0" а по хорошему должно wlan0mon, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой помогите пожалуйста

Comment: имя не важно... что показывает dmesg?

Comment: уже разобрался спс